# Overlapping labels with multiple geom_text statements in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I'm making a ggplot with error bars and there is overlapping text on one of them even though I'm using check_overlap = T in the geom_text function

It's mostly an issue with the last hospital

```
ggplot(scores, aes(x=hospital, y=mean), xlab = "score") + 
  geom_point(shape = 19, size = 3) + 
  #geom_line(color="blue") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=hospital, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), color="blue", width=.5) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20), axis.title=element_text(size=25,face="bold"), 
        plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 30)) + 
  ggtitle("Linear Regression Predictions for Scores") + ylab("Score")+ xlab("Hospital") + 
  labs(subtitle = "Data used for Prediction: 2014-2019") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(mean, 1)),vjust = -1, size = 8, check_overlap = T)+ 
  geom_text(aes(y = lower, label = round(lower, 1)),vjust= -1, size = 8, check_overlap = T) + 
  geom_text(aes(y = upper, label = round(upper, 1)),vjust = -1, size = 8, check_overlap = T) 

Dataframe:      
        hospital      mean    lower     upper
1       A             50      40        60
2       B             60      55        65
3       C             80      78        82
4       D             70      65        75
5       E             99      98        100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a long version of the data for the text so you can get it in one call to `geom_text`:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(ggplot2)
scores_long <- hospital %>%
  gather(stat, value, -hospital) %>%
  mutate(value = round(value, 1))

ggplot(data = scores, aes(x=hospital, y=mean), xlab = "score") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=hospital, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), color="blue", width=.5) + 
  geom_point(shape = 19, size = 3) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20), axis.title=element_text(size=25,face="bold"), 
        plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 30)) + 
  ggtitle("Linear Regression Predictions for Scores") + ylab("Score")+ xlab("Hospital") + 
  labs(subtitle = "Data used for Prediction: 2014-2019") +
  geom_text(data = scores_long, 
            aes(label = value, y = value), vjust = -1, size = 8, check_overlap = T)
```

[image]

Comment: If it is really important to see all the text, can also use `geom_text_repel()` in the `ggrepel` package.

Comment: what is the stat and value column for your function here? scores_long <- hospital %>%
  gather(stat, value, -hospital) %>%
  mutate(value = round(value, 1))

Comment: nevermind, I just did melt(scores) and that seemed to work for me. Thanks for your help!